# hyperic sigar: How to get total of ram in GB?

Tags: java, math, sigar

I'm trying to get the Total Ram in Java using [Sigar](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) library, I do the following

```
return String.valueOf(sigar.getMem().getRam());
```

My total RAM is 4GB, so I was expecting `4` or `4.00` but the result is `4008`.

I tried the following:

```
long x = sigar.getMem().getTotal();
final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(x) / Math.log10(1024));
return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.##")
           .format(x / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
```

but still I'm having the result of `3.91 GB`.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably *have* 3.91 physically available GigaBytes, and the math from Sigar is correct.

Check if your BIOS is reserving some RAM for the integrated graphics device or some other devilry.

Comment: is that so. . . then it's OK... I thought there's something wrong because in `Control Panel > System > Basic info. about my computer` it show 4.00 GB, anyway thank you!

Comment: IIRC, 0.1 is rounded to 1 in Windows RAM calculations, eg. 3.90 is 3.90, 3.91 is 4, but feel free to test it on another system to be sure